# Android NDK: C++ runtime restrictions when using prebuilt shared libraries

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries, std

I have a project that uses `gnustl_static` as the c++ runtime, which is globally set in Application.mk.

In the project, I'd like to include now a prebuilt shared library from a 3rd party that implements some functionality. For this I use the `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` mechanism that the NDK build system provides:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := xyzAPI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libxyz-api.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and then later to use it in the main Android.mk

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += xyzAPI
```

From the 3rd party I know that libxyz-api.so has been created using the `c++_shared` runtime.

Question 1: Do I need to care about the fact that my dependency library has been built with a different runtime? If yes, does it mean that I'd have to move my entire project to `c++_shared`?

Question 2: Since dependency xyzAPI has been built with the `c++_shared` runtime do I now have to load up `c++_shared` on the Java side of things (i.e. `System.loadLibrary("c++_shared");`)?

Answer (score 3):

1. This is definitely a valid concern. Using different c++ runtimes within a project is not impossible, but tricky and dangerous.
2. Since **[jb-mr2](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/18/changes.html)** (API level 18) the system will do it for you (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34416). But it's your responsibility to have the relevant **.so** file packaged in your APK, including all relevant ABI variations.

In summary, I believe that switching to **c++_shared** is easier than to watch for all possible failures.

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8877585/192373 for some hints - note that this answer speaks about Windows and Visual Studio, so it is not immediately applicable to your case.